# Llamar funcion desde pagina html

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Cordial saludo, estoy intentando llamar una funcion de javascript que me devuelve el digito de verificación de la Dian para cada fila de una tabla de html, pero genera un error como si no reconociera la función.

Esta es la manera en que llamo la funcion en mi archivo index.blade.html:

```
<td>
    {{ $supplier->Person->pers_razonsocial }}
    {{ $supplier->Person->pers_tipoid }} 
    {{ $supplier->Person->pers_identif }}<br>
    {{ getDV($supplier->Person->pers_identif) }}
</td>
```

al final de ese archivo referencio al archivo de funciones asi:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/supplier/functions.js') }}"></script>
```

y la funcion está en el archivo functions.js (no la incluyo completa porque es muy larga):

```
function getDV(nit) {
   ...
}
```

Pero me devuelve el error:
`Error Call to undefined function getDV() (View:` `C:\laragon\www\Carwash\resources\views\suppliers\index.blade.php)`

que puedo hacer?

Comment: Blade = Servidor (PHP) en donde no existe un motor o intérprete Javascript. Eso significa que no puedes ejecutar funciones de Javascript dentro de una plantilla Blade durante el proceso de creación de la página. Sé que cuesta entenderlo, sobre todo porque esa es una de las maldiciones que recae sobre PHP, hace pensar que puedes intercambiar PHP y Javascript como si fueran calcetines. Probablemente necesites crear tu propia implementación de `getDV` en PHP o dejar que sea Javascript el que llene esos valores de forma dinámica mediante llamadas Ajax a tu servidor. Saludos

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar a cada fila del HTML una clase o id unico para despues dentro de tu función getDV() obtengas dichas filas con querySelector, posteriormente al final de tu script llamas a tu función de tal que forma que al llamar al script como lo estas haciendo actualmente, obtengas las filas que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Esto esta mal y es incompatible:

```
{{ getDV($supplier->Person->pers_identif) }}
```

esta linea de codigo esta en tu PHP o plantilla entonces tu motor php intentara llamar a esa funcion desde PHP como si existiera en PHP, cosa que no es lo que quieres hacer ... o eso es lo que se entiende ...

lo que puedes hacer es crear un evento en tu plantilla en formato html+javascript:

```
 <td onClick="getDV(\'' .$supplier->Person->pers_identif. '\')" ...........
```

aun asi no me convence ninguna de estas soluciones o apaños como te dijeron en el comentario es preferible que hagas los request necesarios para poblar tu tabla y utilizar delegados de javascript para los eventos on click:

algo asi:

```
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const { target } = e;
  if (target.matches('li')) {
    callback(); // If target is an li, run callback
  }
});
```

o algo asi:

```js
document.querySelector("fieldset[data-role=controlgroup]").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.parentNode.classList.contains("ui-button")) tgt = tgt.parentNode; // clicked the span
  if (tgt.classList.contains("ui-button")) {
     console.log(tgt.id,tgt.textContent);
  }
})
```

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Camera Type:</legend>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnDSLR">DSLR<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnPointAndShoot">Point & Shoot<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnNoCamara">No Camara<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
  </fieldset>
  <span id="which"></span>
</div>
```

***Tendrias que adaptarlo a tus necesidades...***

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios, voy a probar sus sugerencias.